# For a game in which every pair has to play with every other pair, total number of games which will be played?

Tags: combinatorics

> A certain game is played between pairs -- one pair plays on a team against another pair. If there are $6$ players available, and every pair has to play with every other pair, what is the total number of games which must be played ?

MY APPROACH:
$6$ players can be divided into $3$ pairs in $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ ways.Moreover 3 pairs may play in $3$ ways with each other.The answer evaluates to  $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}.3=270$.

However this answer is wrong.Can you point out the mistake?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that the game is played between two pairs of people, i.e. 4 people at once?

Comment: Why so?I first made 3 pairs from 6 people and then calculated that number of ways the pairs can play with each other  (2 pairs at a time) is 3. @6005

Comment: I wasn't saying why your number was wrong (I have now explained that in my answer). I was saying you didn't explain the problem very well. But I clarified it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to being correct. The error is

> $6$ players can be divided into $3$ pairs in $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ ways.

This is wrong because you are counting each way of dividing them into 3 pairs in $6$ different ways. So you should divide by $6$ to get the correct number of ways to group them into 3 pairs.

Other than this, your calculation is correct.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot :-).I found another method of solving this problem in my book's solution..however I could not understand it completely.Can you explain the following method?$({{6}\choose {2}}{{4}\choose {2}})/2$ is the way of selecting two pairs and their product divided by two gives the number of matches.My question is why should we divide by 2 at the end ?

Comment: @ZOZ $\binom{6}{2}$ selects one pair and $\binom{4}{2}$ selects the other. But we could have selected them in either order, so we divide by $2$.